# Avoiding unnecessary width allocation in container after text wrap

Tags: css

I have a div with a max-width:

HTML:

```
<div>
    Text containing words of protracted length
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    max-width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

When text wraps in the div, the div width is rendered at its max width, even though the text does not take up that whole width:

[image: Example of wasted horizontal space]
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrsnyder/zkr8rput/)

Is there any way to have the container only allocate the minimum amount of horizontal space after a text wrap has occurred?

Comment: No, I don't think you can without a lot of work. I believe that in the absence of a width value on the internal content the div will automatically assume it's max width - see - http://jsfiddle.net/zkr8rput/3/

Comment: There is no easy way in CSS to shrink the div when the words wrap. I have seen a simple javascript method before, there will be an answer on Stack Overflow somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you know beforehand what the text will be, and where you want to break it, just do:

```
div {
    width: 10em;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Here I used 10em to wrap after your first three words. You just have to experiement to get the exact value to use for any particular text. Use em units (not pixels) so that it works whatever text magnification the users are running with.

Answer (score 0):

This really only helps with larger blocks, but you can set the div to display: inline-block;

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 2000px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>Text containing words of protracted length</div>
```